# Ubuntu server stops serving content/responding to SSH after a while

Tags: ubuntu, freeze, ubuntu-11.04

On my server with Ubuntu 11.04 I run a web server and an irssi session within screen.

The server freezes after a while. When I try to access its web pages, it only says "Loading" before it timeouts. When trying to connect through SSH I get no response followed by a timeout.

However, ping is responding and the auto-op feature on irssi still works.

A reboot is the only way I have found that solves it.

What could be the problem? How can I log the performance and status of the system to get more info on what is going wrong?

Comment: How do you reboot it after it stops responding? A hard reboot by cutting the power, or can you still access a terminal directly on the machine?

Comment: Have you checked the system log?

Comment: Which system log do you exactly mean?
I can hard reset it. Console is frozen too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What could be the problem?

I would attempt to log in to the console and see what processes were running.

I would look in syslog for error messages that might give a clue.

I would use tools like `top` to monitor the system after a restart (assuming the "freezes after a while" implies a predicable period of time).

There may be a hardware problem (e.g. memory) - so I'd consider running some hardware diagnostics.

Comment: I haven't got physical access to that server. It's virtual server running at one company. (helpdesk didn't help = your virtual machine = your problem)
So, let's try syslog and top.. But after a while is about 1-2 days ;)

Comment: @Blaskovic: Apparently, some virtual hosting companies provide virtual console access through the web-based vhosting control-panel available to customers (they may refer to it as out-of-band console access) - I guess the helpdesk would have mentioned it though.

Comment: Yes, they have KVM (vnc). It's frozen too.

Comment: Thank you. I found syslog. It's problem with procesor. It's not strong enough to handle it.